# jQuery.map(....).concat is not a function

Tags: javascript

Why would the following jquery code sometimes throw the error "concat is not a function":

```
var myArray = $('div.foo')
    .filter(function() { return $(this).is('.something'); })
    .map(function() { 
        return [['a', 'b', $(this).val()]];
    });

return myArray.concat(anotherArray);
```

Answer (score 7):

`$().map()` returns a jQuery object, not an array.
jQuery objects do not have a `concat()` method.

You need to call `.get()` to get a real array.

Comment: Ah ok, the jquery documentation is annoying in this regard: "The $.map() method applies a function to each item in an array or object and maps the results into a new array."

Comment: Yes but in this case, you're operating on a jQuery object, not an array. `$.map(myArray, function(){})` is not the same as `$('selector').map(function(){})`

Answer (score 1):

contact is for **ARRAYS**, and not for **OBJECTS**. 
Use: 
1) [Filter Form Parameters Before Submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390861/filter-form-parameters-before-submitting/29374307#29374307)

Or 
2) [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)